# what is the difference between ${variable_name} and $variable_name in shell script

Tags: shell

In Shell script they are declare variable like ${variable_name},Is it equal to $variable_name
what is the difference between  ${variable_name} and  $variable_name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The curly brace form is less ambiguous
>   because if the braces are omitted the
>   shell may not be able to distinguish
>   between a variable name and the text
>   surrounding it.

If you wrote a variable ($myvariable) with the text like this

```
echo foo$myvariablebar
```

Then shell may not be able to distinguish a variable name so you needs to use `{}` here like this

```
echo foo${myvariable}bar
```

Then the shell knows `myvariable` is a variable here  and `bar` is text

Checkout [here](http://www.simtec.co.uk/products/SWABLE/files/able-set/book_user.chapter_cli.section_shvars.html) is a clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks for both question and answer! I was having some trouble figuring out what I could use to delimit a variable name, and now I found it :)